# Group records when date is within N minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

It's not as simple as creating intervals of time that are N minutes long. One record might be 10:04, and the other 10:17 where N is 15.

Perhaps a user-function will work, maybe a CTE. It could require multiple joins on the same source table.

I'm looking for the most "elegant" solution. Maybe there's a feature in SQL I didn't know about which makes this easy.

Here is a reference scenario to make answers more consistent with each other:

```
create table Comparisons (
  DateField DateTime NOT NULL,
  Amount int not null, -- default to 5
)

insert into Comparisons (DateField) values ('2000-01-01 10:04'),('2000-01-01 10:17'),
('2000-01-01 12:01'),('2000-01-01 11:54'),('2000-01-01 03:02'),('2000-01-01 03:05'),
('2000-01-01 05:02'),('2000-01-01 05:05'),('2000-01-01 05:19')
```

output expected:

- min: .. 10:04, max: .. 10:17, sum: 10
- min: .. 11:54, max: .. 12:01, sum: 10
- min: .. 03:02, max: .. 03:05, sum: 10
- min: .. 05:02, max: .. 05:19, sum: 15 [optional]

The last output is optional, but if an elegant solution has that as a side-effect, it's acceptable. If an elegant solution can't achieve that optional last output, it won't be a deal breaker.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  As written, the question is pretty meaningless.

Comment: @GordonLinoff done. I was already onto it, just followed up.

Comment: What do you do if, say, N = 15 and you have times 10:04, 10:17 and 10:25?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking makes sense. If you have 10 records that span 8 minutes, and each record is evenly spaced in time, how would you group those? You can't group the first and last record together because they're more than 5 minutes apart. And two adjacent records that are less than a minute apart may or may not be grouped together.

Comment: @ZLK very good question. All 3 should be grouped together.

Comment: So for as long as there's anything within N minutes of a given time, they should be grouped?

Comment: @ZLK That's sounds correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this produces the results you want:

```
DECLARE @Comparisons TABLE (i DATETIME, amt INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(5));
INSERT @Comparisons (i) VALUES ('2016-01-01 10:04:00.000')
, ('2016-01-01 10:17:00.000')
, ('2016-01-01 10:25:00.000')
, ('2016-01-01 10:37:00.000')
, ('2016-01-01 10:44:00.000')
, ('2016-01-01 11:52:00.000')
, ('2016-01-01 11:59:00.000')
, ('2016-01-01 12:10:00.000')
, ('2016-01-01 12:22:00.000')
, ('2016-01-01 13:00:00.000')
, ('2016-01-01 09:00:00.000');

DECLARE @N INT = 15;

WITH T AS (
    SELECT i
         , amt
         , CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, previ, i) <= @N THEN 0 ELSE 1 END RN1
         , CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, i, nexti) > @N THEN 1 ELSE 0 END RN2
    FROM @Comparisons t
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT MAX(i) FROM @Comparisons WHERE i < t.i)x(previ)
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT MIN(i) FROM @Comparisons WHERE i > t.i)y(nexti)
    )
, T2 AS (
    SELECT CASE RN1 WHEN 1 THEN i ELSE (SELECT MAX(i) FROM T WHERE RN1 = 1 AND i < T1.i) END mintime
         , CASE WHEN RN2 = 1 THEN i ELSE ISNULL((SELECT MIN(i) FROM T WHERE RN2 = 1 AND i > T1.i), i) END maxtime
         , amt
    FROM T T1
    )
SELECT mintime, maxtime, sum(amt) total
FROM T2
GROUP BY mintime, maxtime
ORDER BY mintime;
```

It's probably a little clunkier than it could be, but it's basically just grouping anything within an @N-minute chain.

Comment: Very well written answer, thanks. It is a bit clunky looking, but if it works it's better than one of my ideas (loop and adjust temp table). That's some serious SQL with OUTER APPLY and more. That initial code will make it very easy for others to efficiently contribute an answer too!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to group records based on gaps between them of at least <N> minutes.

In SQL Server 2012+, you would use `lag()` to identify when groups start and cumulative sum to identify the groups:

```
select min(datefield), max(datefield), count(*) as num, sum(amount)
from (select c.*,
             sum(case when prev_datefield < dateadd(minute, -N, datefield)
                      then 1 else 0
                 end) over (order by datefield) as grp
      from (select c.*,
                   lag(datefield) over (order by datefield) as prev_datefield
            from Comparisons c
           ) c
      ) c
group by grp;
```

In earlier versions you can use correlated subqueries or `apply` for the same functionality (albeit at much worse performance).

Comment: very interesting - Lag() : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/hh231256.aspx

Comment: instead of dateadd, it might need `abs(datediff(minute, prev_datefield, TreatmentRecordDateTime)) < N`. But aside from that, the biggest challenge is assigning a group key. This might need to be coupled with some sort of anonymous/keyless grouping, if that's even possible. It might not be possible with window functions.

Answer (score 0):

Intervals could be used, if adjacent intervals are checked. This would require multiplying the source table records by 3

Pseudo-code:

```
select *
from Comparisons C, {-1, 0, 1} M
group by (datediff(mi, C.DateField, 0) / N) + M
```

The problem with this approach is how to eliminate the extra results. I suspect this is a deadend approach but someone else might see value in it.

Update: This approach would not work with the 4th expected output [min: .. 05:02, max: .. 05:19, sum: 15]

Comment: What do the curly braces do in SQL Server?

Comment: It's pseudo-code - it means a literal set of 3 rows. This answer is here to work through the idea, and get others thinking outside the box. I don't have enough knowledge of the SQL functions to come up with the answer on my own. Hence the question.